# react routing this.props.history.push pathname is not working

Tags: reactjs

My current link is http://localhost:3000/show/.On this page i am using on video player component and after playing video link will generate like http://localhost:3000/video.But my expected result is http://localhost:3000/show/video.
I am using

```
   this.props.history.push({
     pathname: this.props.match.url/video,
  });
```

and in route file i am using  <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/Video`} component={Video} />
but not routing video component. My expected result will http://localhost:3000/show/video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead to use string templating to form a valid path string:

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: `${this.props.match.url}/video`,
});
```

Comment: i am using same thing pathname: `${this.props.match.url}/video` but not routing video components.

Comment: @bdevloper I don't quite follow this comment, it's unclear what you are saying.

Comment: i am on   <http://localhost:3000/show/> page and I want navigate to video component.I am navigating  video component but my generating url is <http://localhost:3000/video>.I want to navigate like  this url <http://localhost:3000/show/video> .

Comment: @bdevloper Is `/video` a nested route in `/show`? Check this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-routing-this-props-history-push-pathname-is-not-working-c6dxu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fexample.js&theme=dark)

Comment: thanks for reply Sir.I will implement this and get back to you Sir.

Comment: Thanks Sir I implement ass per demo its working using Link.Below is my demo link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ffpwb7?file=src/component/shows/shows.js